# Why isn't ownKeys Proxy trap working with Object.keys()?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

In the [documentation of the Proxy `ownKeys` trap on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/ownKeys#Interceptions) it states that it will intercept `Object.keys()` calls:

> This trap can intercept these operations:
>
> Object.getOwnPropertyNames()
>
> Object.getOwnPropertySymbols()
>
> Object.keys()
>
> Reflect.ownKeys()

However, from my tests it doesn't seem to work with `Object.keys`:

```js
const proxy = new Proxy({}, {
  ownKeys() {
    console.log("called")
    return ["a", "b", "c"]
  }
})

console.log(Object.keys(proxy))

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proxy))

console.log(Reflect.ownKeys(proxy))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is simple: `Object.keys` returns only properties with the enumerable flag. To check for it, it calls the internal method `[[GetOwnProperty]]` for every property to get its descriptor. And here, as there’s no property, its descriptor is empty, no enumerable flag, so it’s skipped.

For `Object.keys` to return a property, we need it to either exist in the object, with the enumerable flag, or we can intercept calls to [[GetOwnProperty]] (the trap getOwnPropertyDescriptor does it), and return a descriptor with enumerable: true.

Here’s an example of that:

```js
let user = { };

user = new Proxy(user, {
  ownKeys(target) { // called once to get a list of properties
    return ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  },

  getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, prop) { // called for every property
    return {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true
      /* ...other flags, probable "value:..." */
    };
  }

});

console.log( Object.keys(user) ); // ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

[Source](https://javascript.info/proxy)

Answer (score 2):

`Object.keys` returns only the *enumerable* own properties of an object. Your proxy doesn't have such, or at least it doesn't report them in its `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` trap. It works with

```js
const proxy = new Proxy({}, {
  ownKeys() {
    console.log("called ownKeys")
    return ["a", "b", "c"]
  },
  getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, prop) {
    console.log(`called getOwnPropertyDescriptor(${prop})`);
    return { configurable: true, enumerable: true };
  } 
})

console.log(Object.keys(proxy))

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proxy))

console.log(Reflect.ownKeys(proxy))
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const proxy = new Proxy({}, {
ownKeys: function () {
  console.log("called")
  return ["a", "b", "c"]
  }
 });
```

Comment: While possibly correct, a code-only answer helps the person who asked the question, it doesn't do them or future visitors any good.   Please consider improving your answer.

Comment: my friend i test code  and work's fine. what should i do to improve answer